# Installation SharePoint Foundation 2010 - Error Startup task doesn't exist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got into a trouble that whenever I click on Prerequisite, I got the error log as below. Then, I tried to install with another computer and get the same problem. Please let me know what I am facing to.

```
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Processor architecture is (9)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Common Startup
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - from the following registry location...
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - The value is... 
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\SharePointFoundation\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Bytes read: (0)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Command line arguments from the file:
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Arguments: 
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Details of the current operating system: 
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (1)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X1DB1=7601)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (1)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X100=256)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_WORKSTATION
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Product type:  (0)
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Error: This tool supports Windows Server version 6 and version 6.1
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2015-06-09 14:00:40 - Cannot retry
2015-06-09 14:00:42 - Opening log file
2015-06-09 14:00:42 - Opened action for user
2015-06-09 14:00:42 - C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\PrerequisiteInstaller.2015.06.09-14.00.40.log
```

Comment: Which server version are you trying it to install to? If you are on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 this won't work

Comment: I am heading to install SP on my windows 7. Last time, I installed it completely. However, I cannot right now.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44210/Installing-SharePoint-Server-on-Windows-x
or
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/373724/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows

Key steps:

- extract Sharepoint installation medium to your disk
- open config.xml
- append `<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>` in the `<configuration></configurtion> section`
- Install

Please note: If you are running on a 32bit version of Windows, Client-OS or Server, you won't be able to install SharePoint no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, for the first link, I cannot find `oserver2010` in folder `MSECache`, for the second one, I also tried but I still got that problem. I am using 64 bit OS and Windows 7 Pro.